# LINQ to SQL: If database return no values Count() throws an exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, null

I have a linq to sql statement which returns a set of Customer details to a customer object

```
var customers = from .....
```

I then use

```
if(customers.Count() > 0)
{
    return customers.First();
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

but customers.Count() 
throws a

```
'customers.Count()' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'   int {System.NotSupportedException}
```

how else am I to check if nothing was returned???

=============

This is what the problem was. It was actually a problem in my LINQ statement
I was doing

I have a function

```
bool TrimAndCompare(string s1, string s2)
{
   return customer.CustomerID.Trim() == customerID.Trim()
}

var customers = from customer in _context.Customers
                          where
                                TrimAndCompare(customer.CustomerID, customerID)
                          select customer;
```

When I did this everything is good

```
var customers = from customer in _context.Customers
                          where
                                customer.CustomerID.Trim() == customerID.Trim()
                          select customer;
```

**Guess you can't reuse functions in a LINQ statement then**

Comment: can you show the rest of your Linq expression

Answer (score 6):

You can't use methods that have no equivalent in SQL in a Linq-To-SQL expression.

---

In order to test for results, don't use *Count* and *First* as this would execute the SQL query twice.
Instead, use *FirstOrDefault*:

```
return customers.FirstOrDefault();
```

[FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) returns the first element, or *null* if no elements were found:

Comment: gives me the same exception as above